# How to change cursor to "finger pointer" when rolling over hide/show text (javascript)

Tags: javascript

On my website I have some hide/show JavaScript (below).  It is used commonly in FAQs where you see a list of questions and when rolling over the question it changes color and clicking on it opens text.

I would like the cursor to change to a "finger pointer" (the usual shape of when something is linked) when rolling over the text.

What should be added to the code below?

The words MY TEXT represent the various text I put in specific to my site.

Thank you!

```
<a onclick="javascript:ShowHide('item')"> MY TEXT </a>
<div class="mid" id="item" style="display: none;"><p> MY TEXT </p></div>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function ShowHide(divId)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` in `onclick` attributes. That's only needed when you put JS in `href`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `cursor: pointer;` css rule:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:ShowHide('item')"> MY TEXT </a>
```

Also, you can make that JS a bit prettier:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
function ShowHide(divId){
   var el = document.getElementById(divId);
   el.style.display = el.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
}
// ]]></script>
```

I would also advise you: **Don't use inline styles.**
Create a stylesheet, use classes, style those classes, and than assign those classes to your HTML elements.

For example:

```
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: orange;
    /* etc... style here your anchors */
}
a:hover {
    /* place here style for the hovered anchors */
}
.hidden {   /* add that class to any HTML element you want initially hidden */
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was a perfect answer and I really appreciate your taking the time to help me out!  Changes made!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `cursor: pointer;` in CSS to your element.

Let's say you want to add it to a div:

```
div { cursor: pointer; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/wnn3s0yk/2/